# php увеличение количества итераций

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть функция, на вход которой передается `ID $select`, а далее, в самом начале тела функции этот номер пушится в массив `$nextItems`.
Далее в фориче я перебираю этот массив, подставляя в запрос этот ID. Полученные записи я обрабатываю во внутреннем цикле `for` и добавляю их ID в этот же массив `$nextItems` методом `array_push()` для последующей рекурсии в фориче, а после отрабатывания итерации форича убираю текущий `ID` методом `array_shift()` в строку `$used` для фильтрации последующих запросов.
Но засада в том, что форич отрабатывает только первый раз, хотя я до завершения первой итерации добавляю новые элементы.

```
$select = 1;
$nextItems = [];
array_push($nextItems, $select);
$visited = '';

foreach ($nextItems as $nextItem){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_x = $nextItem";
    for(){
    ...
    ...
    array_push($nextItems, $newItem);
    }
    ...
    $usedArray = array_shift($nextItems);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пытаться изменять массив, по которому вы проходите именно сейчас в foreach - дурацкая идея. Для PHP5 это неопределённое поведение, для PHP7 - обход цикла осуществляется по копии массива.

Насколько понимаю, на самом деле вы пытаетесь сделать очередь. Соответственно, вам нужен цикл

```
while (! empty($nextItems)) {
```

или, что из-за приведения типов эквивалентно, но компактнее,

```
while ($nextItems) {
```

Это к вопросу, почему код себя ведёт не так. А к вопросу, что лучше с этим сделать - возьмите стандартный [SplQueue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php). Не эталон реализации очереди, но работает куда лучше, чем на каждой итерации копировать весь массив заново (так себя ведёт `array_shift`).

Comment: а чуть подробнее =  *для PHP7 - обход цикла осуществляется по копии массива* - а если он изменяется, то изменения только по выходу из цикла доступны? Или в 7ке просто изменять нельзя?

Comment: Это вот про эту rfc: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php7_foreach Т.е. в php7 как раз поправили поведение foreach - обход как в вопросе по значению - изменения исходного массива не повлияют на поведение цикла, т.к. цикл обходит копию начального массива. Обход цикла по ссылке - будет вести себя более ожидаемым образом.

Comment: ага. почитаю. спасибо!